# Redirect url in Apache

Tags: apache, tomcat6

I have two websites

1. www.DomainA.com
2. www.DomainA.**co.uk**

I'm using an Apache web server with tomcat.

I want all the urls from www.DomainA.com to be redirected to www.DomainA.**co.uk** while preserving the url and only changing the domain name.

I am using mod_jk to forward the requests to tomcat. Below is my config:

**workers.properties :**

```
worker.list=worker1

worker.worker1.type=ajp13

worker.worker1.port=8009
```

**httpd.conf:**

```
<IfModule jk_module>

JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties

JkLogFile     logs/mod_jk.log

JkLogLevel    info

JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "

    </IfModule>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
    JkMount /* worker1
    </VirtualHost>
```

**Tomcat server.xml:**

```
  <Host name="www.DomainA.com"  appBase=""
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

    <Context path="/" reloadable="true"
            docBase="/test/home">
            <Logger className="org.apache.catalina.logger.SystemOutLogger"
                    verbosity="4" timestamp="true" />
    </Context>
  </Host>


    <Host name="www.DomainA.co.uk"  appBase=""
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

    <Context path="/" reloadable="true"
            docBase="/test/home">
            <Logger className="org.apache.catalina.logger.SystemOutLogger"
                    verbosity="4" timestamp="true" />
    </Context>
  </Host>
```

I have tried many solutions I found on StackOverflow but somehow it's not working, hence posting this question.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does your apache server sit in front of both domain.co.uk and domain.com?

Comment: Yes, it sits in front of both domain.co.uk and domain.com